# Form freeze while executing a query

Tags: c#, mysql, freeze

Good day.

I'm trying to add a progress bar while consulting a query in `MySql`. I detected that the form freeze exactly when the `DataSet` starts to fill. I also know that the query is complex, so I try to configure a `backgroundworker` and again when it reach the fill process the form freeze and the progress bar don't work until the `DataSet` finish filling. How can I prevent the form freeze or use the `backgroundworker` so the DataSet fill work `async` with the progress bar?

My code is this:

```
try
{
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(SetValueForQuery, Conector());
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    **da.Fill(ds); **
     SetValueForDataSet = ds;
}
finally
{
    Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}
```

Comment: Fill needs to happen on another thread, use a Task, async/await, etc...  You're blocking the GUI thread.

Comment: Fill Dataset Async https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50208241/fill-dataset-async

Answer (score 1):

You should try to make the query asynchron.

Example:

```
public void Main(String[] args){
   Thread asyncWorker = new Thread(Work); //Creates the Thread
   asyncWorker.Start(); //Starts the Thread
   Console.ReadKey(); //Makes the Main Thread busy
}
public void Work(){
   while(true)
      Console.WriteLine("I'm busy");
}
```